# How to Split the number into a specific range(between 1000) in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

For example if the number is `4569`.
i need the output as

```
1 - 1000
1001 - 2000
2001 - 3000
3001 - 4000
4000 - 4569
```

I wrote the logic in JAVA for this now but I am migrating my code to UNIX. Is there any single liner to split the numbers with specific range?

Comment: What did you try until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a one-liner with awk. If you have a recent bash you could use bash arithmetics. It's not as fast tho.

`sample.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

(( max = $1 ))
(( num = 0 ))
echo "going for " $max

while (( max >= num )); do
    (( prev = num + 1 ))
    (( num = prev + 999 ))
    if (( num >= max )); then
            echo $prev "-" $max
    else
            echo $prev "-" $num
    fi
done
```

which prints

```
$ ./sample.sh 4569
going for  4569
1 - 1000
1001 - 2000
2001 - 3000
3001 - 4000
4001 - 4569
```

You can modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{e=999;m=4569;for(i=1;i<=m;i+=1000){k=m-i;if(k<1000){e=k};print i" - "i+e}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or POSIX compatible:

```
#!/bin/sh
max=4569
num=1

while [ "$num" -lt "$max" ]; do
  next=`expr "$num" + "999"`
  [ "$next" -gt "$max" ] && next="$max"
  echo "$num - $next"

  num=`expr "$next" + "1"`
done
```